# AMP Cache Public RSA Key invalidation problem

Tags: amp-html

Since our initial configuration according to `https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache` , we were successfully using the `/update-cache/c/s/` endpoint for cache purge. Until yesterday, when we accidentally removed the public/private keys that we were using..!

So.. obviously the problem is that the AMP Cached Public RSA key now differ from our current(new) public rsa key.

(I am using `example.com` below for privacy reasons. Sorry about that)

We generated a new pair but the cached RSA Key does not revalidate even though we tried to revalidate it via

`curl -XGET https://www-example-com.cdn.ampproject.org/r/s/www.example.com/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub -v`

**Detailed info**

Our new public key is:

1. served by webserver in `text/plain` format
2. available at `https://www.example.com/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub`
3. configured to be `BYPASSED` by cdn & server cache (Cloudflare & nginx).
4. allowed (via robots.txt) to be crawled/indexed by all bots `Allow: /.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub`

FULL robots.txt:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /wp-login.php
Disallow: /?s=
Disallow: /search/
Allow: /.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*?*smid=
Disallow: /*?*partner=
Disallow: /*?*utm_source=
```

URL Formats:

1. AMP Cache Check:

```
https://www-example-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.example.com/article-slug/amp/
```

2. AMP RSA Key Revalidation:

```
https://www-example-com.cdn.ampproject.org/r/s/www.example.com/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub
```

3. AMP Cache Purge/Update:
   (Auto generated by AMP Cache Update URL Generator https://github.com/enteresanlikk/amp-cache-update)

```
https://www-example-com.cdn.ampproject.org/update-cache/c/s/www.example.com/article-slug/amp/?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=<timestamp>&amp_url_signature=<signature>
```

Since the two RSA keys are different, we are now getting a 403 URL signature verification error.

24 hours have passed since the key change..
Is there any way that we can force the old cached RSA key to invalidate/re-cache ?

Or are am i doing anything wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. It was not an issue after all... Just needed to wait a little longer.
RSA Key updated and afterwards AMP Cache cleared as normal!

Everything i described is correct. Leaving it as a guide for others.

Thanks